# Question title disappears when page reloads

Tags: bug, title, draft

This has been happening for so long (years) that I just took it for granted and never questioned it until now.

Maybe this specifically happens on iPhone SE in Safari, but I think it happens in general.

If you draft a question, and then leave the page and come back some time later (without having actually posted it), and the browser auto-reloads the page, the post text is still there in the body, but the question title is gone. I also think this is the Stack Exchange software which automatically saves entered text in the post body text field, so I’m wondering if the issue is that the title text field is a different kind of HTML element or something? I’m pretty sure the same thing happens on desktop but I can check.

[image: the question title disappeared after the page auto reloaded even though I originally wrote one]